# Error after adding Firebase In-App Messaging SDK for Android

Tags: android, firebase

After adding Firebase In-App Messaging SDK to my build.gradle, I keep getting this error message after building my project `Program type already present: com.google.common.annotations.Beta`
I have tried most the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540827/error-program-type-already-present-com-google-common-annotations-beta/50520218#50520218) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395013/issue-in-adding-firebase-in-app-messaging) but it didn't work for me.

Below are the dependency libraries I am using on the project

```
  def room_version = "1.1.1"
def supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
implementation 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:3.6'
implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.4'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.github.mirrajabi:search-dialog:1.2.3'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'

//support library
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportLibVersion"

// firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.4'



// retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'

//google play services
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

// room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"

//rx java
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.10'

//people api
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev277-1.23.0'

//expandable layout
implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'

//FlutterWave RavePay
implementation 'com.github.Flutterwave:rave-android:1.0.25'

//day picker
implementation 'com.github.DavidProdinger:weekdays-selector:1.0.4'

//Facebook SDK
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.38.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:4.38.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
```

Below is the full error log

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
>       at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1087.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>       ... 33 more
>   Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:144)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>       ... 48 more
>   Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.google.common.annotations.Beta
>       at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:131)
>       ... 51 more
>   Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.google.common.annotations.Beta
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1990)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:124)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:123)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:40)
>       at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:110)
>       at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
>       ... 52 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the gradle dependency graph with `gradle dependencies`. Inspect the graph to locate which libraries use this dependency `com.google.common.annotations.Beta`. You can then use the gradle `exclude` rule to exclude the culprit transitive dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try From menu `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: It's still not building successfully after doing that. Here is the error I now get. 
Error: Program type already present: com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator$State

Answer (score 0):

Remove if you have **com.google.firebase:firebase-core** library.

As per the firebase doc.

**No longer add the Android library com.google.firebase:firebase-core.**
This SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics. Now, to use Analytics (or any of the Firebase products that require or recommend the use of Analytics), **you need to explicitly add the Analytics dependency:**
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0.